# Does 0 * a limited domain value limit the domain?

Tags: functions, logarithms

Say for example, you have:

$$f(x) = x + (0 \cdot \log(x))$$

We know that for $\log(x)$, $x$ must be greater than $0$. However, since it is multiplied by zero in the case of $f(x)$ with the result being a linear function $y = x$, is the domain still limited to $x > 0$?

Can you just say

$$f(x) = x + 0 \cdot \log(x) = x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $0c=0$ for any complex number $c$. However, if $c$ is not a complex number, then we can make no such claim.

Now, there is a world where $\log(x)$ is defined for $x<0$ -- the complex numbers. However, $\log(0)$ is still undefined there. So we can say that $0\log(x)=0$ for all $x\neq 0$, since $\log(x)$ in this case is indeed a complex number. However, $0\log(0)$ is undefined, since $0\cdot\text{undefined}=\text{undefined}$.

In short:

$$x+0\log(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{, if }x\neq0\\
\text{undefined}&\text{, if }x=0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: +1. As usual, the big word is IF. If c is a number then 0c=0 but if c does not exist then 0c doesn't exist either so x+0c doesn't exist either.

Comment: So the domain is still limited if you reduce 0log(0) to 0? This applies to other equations with limited domains?

Comment: Yes, $0\log(x)=0$ only holds if $x\neq 0$. It's just like how $0/x=0$, so long as $x\neq 0$.